# How to publish an android app new license key?

Tags: android, android-lvl

I'm finally ready to publish my first app. I went in to do the paid version and it said I need to add some code to my binary. I have no idea where that is. Here is what it says on the page (the dev guide seems to be out of date for this new method):

```
SERVICES & APIS
LICENSING & IN-APP BILLING
Licensing allows you to prevent unauthorized distribution of your app. It can also be used to verify in-app billing purchases. Learn more about licensing.

YOUR LICENSE KEY FOR THIS APPLICATION
Base64-encoded RSA public key to include in your binary. Please remove any spaces.

"a bunch of random numbers and letters"
```

Comment: @you can accept your previous question's answer if that helps you.

Comment: Accept answers to your previous questions. This gives the people who answered your questions some credit.

Comment: That can be hard to do -- at least two of his five previous questions haven't been answered.

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much have to follow the steps detailed [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#cert).

Comment: That's a page on how to sign your app.  It looks like BRK is running into some requirement to enable DRM licensing in the app. This is news to me -- I've had a paid app in the market for years, and never gotten a notification like this.  I wonder if it's something new?

Comment: I added my own application just about a month ago. The steps I linked to are pretty much all I needed to do. I have published some updates as well and they didn't need an embedded License either.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe this is the answer i was looking for http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html